# android кнопка над всем остальным

Tags: android, xml

Хочу чтобы кнопка была над всем остальным и во время скрола исчезала. Не понимаю как это реализовать

[image: Пример из приложения "net mod syna"]

Вот пример из приложения "netmod syna".
Там при скроле кнопка в нижнем правом углу экрана исчезает + она перекрывает все остальное.

P.S. В android разработке чайник, не бейте сильно

Comment: Используй свойство "visibility" для кнопки в методе onScrollChanged ()

Comment: Спасибо, одна из проблем решена! Но как сделать, так, чтобы при скроле кнопка сохраняла свое абсолютное местоположение на экране и была над всеми остальными элементами?

Comment: Добавь кнопку в FrameLayout с параметром android:layout_gravity="center". Это означает, что кнопка будет находиться в центре экрана, и она будет находиться над другими элементами в FrameLayout.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает!